# R# Generate Switch Labels with braces under case blocks

Tags: c#, resharper

Is it possible to customize the template used by Resharper's "Generate Switch Labels" feature? I'd prefer if it automatically created braces under each `case` label. Looking through options, I can't see anything of the sort.

By default, I get this:

```
switch (myEnum)
{
    case MyEnum.One:
        break;
    case MyEnum.Two:
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(myEnum), myEnum, null);
}
```

Whereas I would like to see this:

```
switch (myEnum)
{
    case MyEnum.One:
    {
        break;
    }
    case MyEnum.Two:
    {
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(myEnum), myEnum, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Folks who want this feature should vote for it on the ReSharper issue tracker here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-71196